# dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.solvescan/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit

Tags: kivy, apk, virtualbox, opencv, buildozer, python

I tried to build and android apk file using buildozer and VM (Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit).
Apk file was built without problems, but when I tried to install the app on android and run it, "adb logcat" command showed me the following error:

dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.solvescan/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit

By the way, I tried to build apk file on the same VM but without using cv2 library and it worked without any error.

Comment: Did you put `opencv` in the requirements? If you wrote `opencv-python` that would lead to this issue.

Comment: I wrote "opencv-python". I try your variant now.